# Javascript:Audio playing while clicking on image

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick

I want an audio to be played when I click on an image, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

**HTML**:

```
  <.img id="horse" src="kon.png".>
```

(without dots at the ends)

**JS**:

```
prr = function() {
        var ryk = document.createElement("audio")
        ryk.src = "ya.mp3"
        document.body.appendChild(ryk)

    }
    var kon = document.getElementById("horse")
    kon.addEventListener("click", prr)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html add this code

```
<audio id="yourSound" style="display:none;">
    <source src="ya.mp3" type="audio/ogg">  
</audio>
```

in you js code add this

```
    yourSound = function () {
        document.getElementById('yourSound')[0].play();
    }

    document.getElementById("horse").on('click', function(){
        yourSound();
    });
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add audio type and style=display?

Answer (score 0):

You must just add **autoplay** attribute.  *And after each line use semicolon*

> ryk.autoplay="*autoplay*"

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ryk.play()` to the `prr` function and run the code when the document is ready:

```js
function prr() {
  var ryk = document.createElement( 'audio' );
  ryk.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3';
  document.body.appendChild( ryk );
  ryk.play()
}

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById( 'horse' ).addEventListener( 'click', prr)
})
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<img id="horse" src="http://www.thinkmaze.com/wp-content/uploads/Red_Button_ThinkMaze.jpg" width="300", height="200">
```

Comment: Haha thanks for help,i learned what i wanted and even more(didn't know about cursor:pointer attribute),btw this horse's sound is much better

Comment: CSS can generate a bunch of different mouse cursors. The cursor property specifies the mouse cursor to be displayed when pointing over an element. In this case, when you put the cursor on image, the cursor change to hand icon.